# Wrapping procedure calls in one main procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have four working stored procedures (DB2), each accepting their own parameters, but a lot of those params are the same.

I'm trying to create a larger wrapper procedure that will basically just call each in order. There are about 10 outside values coming into the wrapper procedure as it's own parameters.

Within the body, where I call all 4 child parameters, I will be using a mixture of outside params as well as a main ID param that is derived from the first call.

How can I properly wrap these four procedure calls using the outside params as well as the captured/derived parameter from my first call?

Parameters:

````
FIRST_NAME
LAST_NAME
PROFILE_IMAGE
CODE
START_DATE
EXPIRE_DATE
PRIORITY
CUST_NUMBER
CONTACT_TYPE
CONTACT_VALUE


CALL FIRST_PROC(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PROFILE_IMAGE)
    --This returns ```FIRST_PROC_ID```

CALL SECOND_PROC(FIRST_PROC_ID, CODE,START_DATE,EXPIRE_DATE,PRIORITY)

CALL THIRD_PROC(FIRST_PROC_ID,CODE,CUST_NUMBER,START_DATE,EXPIRE_DATE,PRIORITY)

CALL FOURTH_PROC(FIRST_PROC_ID,CONTACT_TYPE,CONTACT_VALUE,START_DATE,EXPIRE_DATE)
````

Comment: Pass the supplied parameters into each sproc, and output the result of the first sproc to a variable.

Are you asking how to output the result of the first sproc to where you can use it in the other 3?

Or are you asking how to write a stored procedure?

Comment: I feel comfortable in this situation with writing the proc because I'm basically just calling for procedures in the body of this one with their own parameters. My biggest question is how to capture output of one of the procedures in the body to be used in the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GET DIAGNOSTICS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005647.html) statement.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1(P_FIRST_PROC_ID INT)
BEGIN
  RETURN P_FIRST_PROC_ID;
END@

BEGIN
  DECLARE V_RC INT;
  CALL TEST1(10);
  GET DIAGNOSTICS V_RC = DB2_RETURN_STATUS;
  CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Return Status: '||V_RC);
END@
```

Comment: So if my first call returns resource-I'd, I can use that statement to return that and use it in the next call?

Comment: Yes. See the example above, which must print the `Return Status: 10` string if you run it with DB2 CLP.